# SMS Fu Ruby gem throwing very strange YAML error

Tags: ruby, sms, yaml

I'm trying to use the Ruby [SMS Fu](https://github.com/brendanlim/sms-fu) gem to send automated SMS messages to someone from my email address. Also, I'm not using Rails; this is a simple Ruby script that's getting some information from a site somewhere and then sending messages to someone based on said information. Unfortunately, I'm running into a very strange error when I try to use SMS Fu in my script:

```
/Users/my_username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse': (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 7 column 12 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/my_username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/my_username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:325:in `parse'
    from /Users/my_username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:252:in `load'
    from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sms_fu-1.1.2/lib/sms_fu/sms_fu.rb:55:in `config_yaml'
    from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sms_fu-1.1.2/lib/sms_fu/sms_fu.rb:61:in `carriers'
    from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sms_fu-1.1.2/lib/sms_fu/sms_fu.rb:77:in `carrier'
    from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sms_fu-1.1.2/lib/sms_fu/sms_fu.rb:73:in `carrier_email'
    from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sms_fu-1.1.2/lib/sms_fu/sms_fu.rb:85:in `sms_address'
    from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sms_fu-1.1.2/lib/sms_fu/sms_fu.rb:43:in `deliver'
    from ./my_script.rb:69:in `<main>'
```

What I've got going in my script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "active_support" # action_mailer, one of sms_fu's dependencies, throws
                         # an error without this
require "sms_fu"

# gather information from our site...

# Pony delivery via SMTP
PONY_CONFIG = { 
  :via => :smtp, 
  :via_options => {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => "587",
    :user_name            => "me@example.com",
    :password             => "pass",
    :authentication       => :plain, 
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :domain               => "localhost.localdomain"
  }}

sms_fu = SMSFu::Client.configure(:delivery => :pony, :pony_config => PONY_CONFIG)

sms_fu.deliver("123456789", "some carrier", "my message", from: "me@example") # this line triggers the error
```

The odd thing is that this error is complaining about parsing YAML, but according to SMS Fu's README file, I only need to worry about setting up a YAML file if I'm using Rails, which I'm not. However, it seems that, upon examining SMS Fu's sources, it is hard-coded to work with a YAML file in the `SMSFu.config_yaml` method, which is subsequently used indirectly or directly by other methods in SMS Fu, all the way back to `SMSFu::Client#deliver`, which is the one causing the error here.

So, I guess my question is: how can I get this error to stop happening so that I can just send my SMS message without all the YAML hassle?

EDIT:

Forgot to give some version / environment info: I'm running this script on OS X 10.12.2 and I'm using Ruby 2.4.0 (although this Ruby version is manifest in the error above).